# Iterate "matrix" with sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, hql

I have a table `Question`, and I have a table `Options` that has a `questionId` in it as a foreign key, and I have a table `Answers` that is related to a `Research` table, therefore has a `researchId` as a foreign key. I also have a table `Answers_options` that has my `OptionsId` on it registering the answers.

I need to calculate the percentage of answers of structure like a matrix, as shown here:

[image]

I know how to calculate a cell, but when I tried to calculate all the options and the equivalent I failed. I need to be able to calculate the percentage of who answers op1 in the questionY with op1 in the questionX, op1 with op2...

I calculated a cell and it work, but I could not calculate for all options combined of the two question selected.

Edit:
I hope that helps, i tried to add a image that represents my tables, if you need more information i can add more.

[image]
[tables here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63HWy.png)

The column cel op1 with op1 represents the percentage of answers where people responded op1X with op1Y. The percentage is based on the answers of the column. So if one guy answer op1 with op1 and another guy answer op1X with op2Y. It would register as op1X with op1Y as 50% and op1X with op2Y 50% and the op1X with op3Y 0%.

Comment: That looks like an interesting question, but it is difficult to give you advice unless you give a bit more detail. Can you show some raw data. Also - the columns in your example sum to 100%, Should the rows also sum to 100%?

Comment: The columns should sum 100% because is the total of answers of the op1X in relation to op1Y,op2Y and op3Y. To count as a response, a person should have answer op1 of questionX and op1 with questionY. What do you mean as raw data? The tables filled?

Comment: Mb better solution is to read all required data from DB and iterate any way with high level programing language

Comment: Than i will do that, i thought it had a SQL solution but maybe not.

Comment: It'd be easier to answer if you provided the raw sample data that went into the example matrix - as text (not an image). Also, is there a maximum number of options? If yes, what's the maximum number.  Without knowing more, what you described sounds like a PIVOT.

Comment: Also, what exactly do the `answers` and `answers_options` tables represent (aside from the obvious, i.e. "answers")? For example, does one table represent a respondent's answers and the other the correct answer to each question?